# Liquibase dropDefaultValue on PostgreSQL maps to "SET DEFAULT" not "DROP DEFAULT"

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'm running liquibase against a PostgreSQL 9.6 DB and have a dropDefaultValue change to a **NON-NULLABLE** column.

```
- dropDefaultValue:
    columnDataType: VARCHAR(255)
    columnName: bar
    tableName: foo
```

I expected this to result in a `DROP DEFAULT` instruction (as suggested in the docs - https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/drop_default_value.html) but instead I see:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.foo ALTER COLUMN  bar SET DEFAULT NULL
```

With the net effect that the column still has a default value (of NULL) rather than no default at all. Is this to be expected?

Comment: for nullable columns, the default is null unless specified otherwise. So setting the default to null _unsets_ it. This is a correct behavior

Comment: Thanks @HaleemurAli - I should have mentioned that the column was defined as not NULLABLE.

Comment: There is no such thing as "no default at all" (in any database, including Postgres) - if you do not specify a default, that default is `null`

Comment: OK - so if pgadmin shows me two non-nullable varchar column definitions, one of which reports Default without a value at all, the other of which (following this liquibase change) reports Default as `NULL::character varying`, then that's ok and is effectively "the same thing"?

Answer (score 2):

My experiments show that the `pg_attrdef` row vanishes if I run

```
ALTER TABLE ... ALTER ... SET DEFAULT NULL;
```

But maybe there are ways to enter a NULL row.

However that may be, it is fine, and Liquibase isn't doing anything wrong. NULL is the “default `DEFAULT` value”.

A column can be defined as `NOT NULL` and still have a NULL default value — the only consequence is that you can never use the default value for that column.